# Quickly clean and dry highball glasses

Tags: cleaning

How can I quickly and thoroughly wash, and dry a highball glass which is wider in the center than at the entry point.

[image: Highball Glass]

The glass is similar to the one referred to above.

The shape makes it difficult to clean the regular way.

Comment: This doesn't appear to need a lifehack. Why does the normal washing in a sink or dishwasher not work for you?

Comment: The shape makes it difficult to clean well.

Comment: That's what bottle brushes are made for. And no, that's not a hack.

Answer (score 1):

If you are hand washing the glass, I agree with Stephie that you should use a [bottle brush](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004OCLJ) or something similar when cleaning the glass.

The lifehack comes when you want to dry the glass. If you take a dish drying cloth and continuously twist it while feeding it through the mouth of the glass, you will be able to feed it through even small openings and the cloth will expand inside the glass and dry all of the interior as you continue to twist it.

Comment: If that's a hack, 99% of all housewives I know are hackers ;-)

Comment: @Stephie Ha ha, for sure, Stephie - but we knew that already, didn't we, us women, always know plenty of hacks round the house...